# CSS3 Target Div Overlay Webkit Transition

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to add an opacity transition to CSS3 div overlay target?

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/pb7St/

```
#content {
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    z-index:1;
}
.overlaystyle {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #000;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:2;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease;
}
#overlay {
    display:none;
}
#overlay:target {
    display:block;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Is there any other (better) way to close / hide the div? Currently I'm using:

```
href="#_"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is:

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/pb7St/4/)

**CSS**

```css
.overlaystyle {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #000;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:2;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease, visibility 1s 0s; /* added visibility transition */
}
#overlay {
    //display:none;
    visibility:hidden
}
#overlay:target {
    //display:block;
    visibility:visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

*EDITED to add transition to visibility with delay for fade-out effect. Personally, I'd go with JQuery. :)*

Comment: Great, thank you Paulie_D! Would it possible to fade out as well?

Comment: Great, thank you! Works fine. Do you think close the div with „href="#_"“ is a good way?

Comment: Personally, as I said, I'd use a button and JQuery.